# I changed my vps port to 21 and now i cannot login as proftpd is installed in it

Tags: linux, debian

While I was trying to change my port to another I didn't knew if i will give port 21 for vps the v-p-s will be locked, now i am not able to log-in in ssh, i can just log-in to proftpd as it is installed. Is there any way to change my VPS port to 22 in proftpd (the old one)?

I guess someone can solve my issue.

Help appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: I've flagged your question as "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 6):

As you cannot log in to your system using ssh you don't have many options

- Use a console if your vps host provides one.

  - Just log in and edit /etc/ssh/sshd_config appropriately
  - Restart sshd.
- Use recovery mode if your vps host provides one

  - Mount the / partition of your VPS on /mnt of the recovery environment
  - Edit /mnt/etc/ssh/sshd_config appropriately
  - Restart the system
- Contact your VPS hosts and ask for their help.